# How to Batch select in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i have one mock table table_a as below:

```
   id   a   b    c    d  
   1    11  22  33  44  
   2    22  33  44  55  
   3    33  44  55  66  
   4    44  55  66  77  
   5    55  66  77  88  
   6    66  77  88  99  
   7    77  88  99  100  
   8    88  99  11  22
```

suppose the known info is c and d, if i want to get entry id 2 & 6, i can run 
' select * from table_a where (c, d) in ((44,55), (88,99))'.

Here is my question. If this table has 1 million rows , and i want to get 1 thousand rows out , just by knowing their c and d values, is there any better way to do it? My concern to use above script to do it is **performance**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on `(c, d)`, then Oracle should use the index for the `in` query:

```
create index idx_table_a_c_d on table_a(c, d);
```

Comment: @Benson . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?